# What does "invalid_context" in /var/log/audit/audit.log mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, selinux, linux-security-module

I have a SELinux log line from `/var/log/audit/audit.log` as below:

```
*type=SELINUX_ERR msg=audit(1686136392.111:154486): op=security_compute_sid invalid_context="user_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023" scontext=user_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=user_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_dgram_socket*
```

Above line contains **invalid_context**, whose meaning I did not understand.

Before above log was captured, I changes the role of `user_u` using `semanage user -a -R "system_r unconfined_r" -r s0-s0:c0.c1023 user_u` to `semanage user -a -R "system_r sysadm_r" -r s0-s0:c0.c1023 user_u`. Does `invalid_context` mean the changes done were not successful?